# How to filter a JSON in angular

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Say I have a JSON with the following structure:

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlsMv.png)

I have saved this JSON as a variable in my .ts and called it clients.

How can I go through the JSON and fetch all data in it where id = 1? So I'd like to be able to isolate Bob and bob@gmail.com.

Is there a way to do this within the .ts using for on this.clients? Or maybe in the .html with *ngFor? What would be the most simple solution in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to an appropriate object and then filter it using the filter function.
Check it here [Filter function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_filter.htm)

Performance-wise it is better to filter in the ts rather than in the html